# Profiling asp.net core 2 (web api) with angular 5

Tags: angular, profiling, asp.net-core-2.0, mvc-mini-profiler, glimpse

I am looking for Profiling solutions for following environment, could someone suggest please.

- ASP.NET Core 2 on net471
- EntityFramework 6.2.0
- Angular 5.0.0

I looked into **MiniProfiler** & **Glimpse**.

- Glimpse has not been upgraded for Core 2.0 yet.
- MiniProfiler works with **Core 2** but does not work properly for SPA. Someone has tried to extend `http` of **Angular 2** but **Angular 5** now uses `HttpClient` & `interceptor` I think.
- Also I could not figure out how to profile `DataContext (System.Data.Linq)` for SQL profiling using MiniProfile. Docs suggests `Connection` wrapping approch. This is a separate issue I guess.

Comment: Would "Application Insights" help here may be?

Answer (score 3):

If you follow the doc (https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/AspDotNetCore) you should be good to go for the server side. Even to integrate it with EF.

For the Angular 5 integration, I got inspired by this post to write an http interceptor:
https://blog.dangl.me/archive/using-the-stackexchange-miniprofiler-with-an-angular-single-page-application/

Comment: FYI - you can call `MiniProfiler.Current.RenderIncludes(HttpContext)` to generate the `<script>` tag that will be needed to load the tool client-side.  You'll have to decide how/where to inject that script tag into your SPA