# Error Log Profiler for Angular single page UI with Asp.Net Core 2 webApi server side

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi, elmah, glimpse, miniprofiler

I am looking for logging and profiling solution for my web api application developed by c# .NetCore web api and Angular ui. 
I 've read the similar question in stack overflow but that was for about 2 years ago and answers do not help: [Profiling asp.net core 2 (web api) with angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48275132/profiling-asp-net-core-2-web-api-with-angular-5) 
So please help me know about new versions and error logging solutions if there is one... free versions please

Comment: I don't know much about profiling solutions for .NET Core. But for error logging, you can take a look at [elmah.io](https://elmah.io/). It is a commercial solution that helps you log and fix errors from both ASP.NET Core and Angular. Disclamer: I am the founder.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Thomas, could you give me a sample project link for Angular?

Comment: With ASP.NET Core: https://github.com/elmahio/elmah.io.javascript/tree/master/samples/Elmah.Io.JavaScript.Angular. With webpack: https://github.com/elmahio/elmah.io.javascript/tree/master/samples/Elmah.Io.JavaScript.AngularWebpack